# Is the character 攜 still used in modern Chinese?

Tags: characters, character-identification, word, classical-chinese

This character has in classical Chinese a very common meaning, namely "to take", like in the sentence:

攜妻子至海岸。

(To take wife and children and arrive at the sea shore).

I recognize many characters used in classical Chinese in modern Chinese, but I can not remember having seen this particular one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a standard character, simplified 携, meaning carry, take along, hold in hand. A common word is 携带 (carry).

Answer (score 3):

携 is widely used.

For the individual 携, it is official and usually used in written language, but not in spoken language. For example, `奥巴马携妻子到...` (Obama takes his wife to ...).

And 携 also shows in lots of common words. For example, 携带 (carry), 携手 (hand in hand, to collaborate), 提携 (guide and support).

Answer (score 2):

“禁止携带易燃易爆物品”

Is commonly seen on security checkpoints.